# Not sending unchanged input fileds with react hook form

Tags: javascript, reactjs, forms, react-hook-form

I'm using react-hook-form to handle the update for some input fields.

Sometimes the users don't change on all fields, so I do not want to send all changed and unchanged fields with the update API. so my question is there a way to do that ? and just send the changed fields ?

Answer (score 3):

You have `formState.dirtyFields` property that will return all the user modified inputs.

```js
import * as React from "react";
import { useForm, useFormState } from "react-hook-form";

export default function App() {
  const { register, handleSubmit, formState } = useForm();
  const onSubmit = (data) => {
      console.log(formState.dirtyFields);
  };

  return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
      <input {...register("firstName")} placeholder="First name" />
      <input {...register("lastName")} placeholder="Last name" />
      <select {...register("category")}>
        <option value="">Select...</option>
        <option value="A">Category A</option>
        <option value="B">Category B</option>
      </select>

      <input type="submit" />
    </form>
  );
}
```